# Название службы в Windows

Tags: windows, service

Как правильно (по православному MSDN) называется служба в Windows отвечающая за сетевой доступ к файлам - шаре? Подозреваю, что Windows Share, но хотелось бы знать наверняка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MSDN упоминается `File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks`